# Basic PHP image upload not working

Tags: php, http, file-upload

I'm trying to debug an issue with a WordPress 3.5.1 where I cannot upload media via HTTP at all; the media uploader simply says "HTTP error" and fails. To diagnose what's going on, I decided to write (i.e. copy from w3schools) a really basic PHP file uploader to see if there's something weird going on behind the scenes. But for some reason, the `$_FILE` structure doesn't contain any information at all, even in the most basic of examples:

file.php :

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php :

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

In every browser I've tried, with every file I've tried, this just outputs:

```
Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 kB
Stored in:
```

and printing `$_FILES` shows that it is just an empty array.

I'm using `PHP-5` on shared hosting (*lunarpages*), but the `php.ini` file has `file_uploads` on and the size of the files I tried is nowhere even close to the `upload_max_filesize`. I am ready to throw my laptop against a wall, so any help would save me a couple thousand dollars.

Comment: Whats the output, when you discard the if/else and just put `<?php error_reporting_(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); print_r($_FILES); ?>` in the script?

Comment: ^^ True. That being said, it's a pretty basic example, and the output is fairly pathological. I'm not worried about security and all that jazz, I just want to make sure PHP is working as it should.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to that folder?

Comment: what has w3fools.com to do with this question?

Comment: I copied exactly your code and it worked for me. Change the permission of everything to 777 for directories and 666 for files

Comment: @DonRhummy `fileperms('.')` gives me `drwxr-xr-x`, so I'd assume so.

Comment: if you turn on display errors, do you get any? Is this your server or a hosted one?

Comment: @DonRhummy It is a server hosted by Lunarpages. Even with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `display_errors` as Dan suggested, I don't get any errors; it just says `$_FILES` is an empty array.

Comment: If it's hosted by Lunar, I'd give them a call. They might have set up some unusual settings. BTW, if php.ini or .htaccess or any of the relevant ".conf" files don't allow it, those `ini_set` commands won't do anything.

Comment: w3schools.com is an [unreliable source](http://www.w3fools.com/) and should be avoided.

Comment: you should approve some answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This worked for me, $_FILES was not empty, using a common Debian installation, PHP 5.2; try to adjust the permissions of your files and direcotires to 777

Comment: I tried adjusting the permissions to 777 for everything, but that resulted in an Internal Server Error when loading either php file.

Comment: Only thing I can help you is, take a deep look into `phpinfo();` and your hosters settings. >.<

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once with a shared host. Turned out that I had no tmp directory set, therefore nothing was being uploaded. Check with your host that your php.ini is set up correctly and that a tmp directory exists for uploads and that you have write permissions for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target="Your Path";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
} 
else 
{ 
  echo "Unable to move temp file to target.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not yet too late, you should check your apache logs. The most probable cause is that the apache - and so your php interpreter - has no permission to your predefined upload directory.